# NAs replace - r

Tags: r

I want to replace NA in columns campaign by "none". Campaign is character.

```
trx2[trx2$campaign=="<NA>"] <- "none"
```

but it gives me an error "missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames".

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to test for na values is `is.na()`; moreover, you need to subset `tr2x$campaign` and not the whole data.frame. Hence :

```
trx2$campaign[is.na(trx2$campaign)] <- "none"
```